# How to write an Android Database query where a DB column is equal to a string?

Tags: android, database

I'm developing an Android app where it pulls a specific row from the database based on the SimpleDateFormat string. I have a column in the DB called SDATE which holds values like "2012-03-28", and so I'd like to write a query in the form db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy); that does "Select the row where the SimpleDateFormat string is equal to the SDATE column in DATABASE_TABLE". Sounds simple, I know, but I must be having a mental block or something. The SimpleDateFormat already spits out the date in the same format as defined in the SDATE column, so how would this query be written?

Comment: Put SDATE='1967-12-31' in selection argument, other args except table name are nulls, mind the '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your data type from string to DATE

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do something like:

```
db.query(MYTABLE,MYCOLUMNS, "SDATE LIKE '2012-03-28'",SELECTIONARGS, GROUPBY, HAVING, ORDERBY);
```

in other words is just matter of changing the parameter "selection" for your "WHERE" clause.